Can Google Chrome restore tabs in all windows when I am using multiple profiles?
I have a profile with a pink tab bar, and a blue one. I open A and B in pink profile and C and D in blue profile. (Pink is logged in to my work Gmail, and Blue is my personal Gmail) When I quit and restart Chrome, I get my blue window closed and just the pink profile restored, tabs A and B. On another older laptop, I used two browsers for this (Chrome and Brave). Should I go back to that? Or can I get Chrome to actually restore all tabs and windows, as expected. This seems obnoxious and non-sensical.

You might be able to keep the tabs by adding them all to a group. Note that closing a grouped tab removes it from the group, and closing the last one removes the group.

Have you checked the answers given in this question: https://superuser.com/questions/696008/how-to-reopen-all-windows-in-chrome ? Multiple windows may handle the multiple profiles.

I have different profile windows open, but only the windows/tabs related to one profile are re-opening. The other windows are lost.
